# Parent pom with definitions that shouldn't be inherited

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I am trying to build a parent pom . I'm not using dependencyManagement or pluginManagement.  I want all the children to inherit everything.

However, the parent project itself has a specific build requirement that I'm using the maven-jar-plugin for.  I don't want the child to inherit this piece.  Is there a way to indicate sections that shouldn't be inherited by the child project?

However, the child projects *do* also use the maven-jar-plugin for another section.  Essentially, I have

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
         <execution>
               
         </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
       <archive>
       
       </archive>            
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

I want the configuration section to be inherited by all the children, but the execution section is only for the parent

Comment: I don't immediately think you're something that is impossible. But I just want to call out that a parent can only be of type POM, so that it would typically not have much use for the JAR plugin _itself_.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I realized that.  I was trying to make our 'common' jar into a parent, but realized I can't do that.  So I switched to making the parent an 'empty' project

Answer (score 1):

Put the configuration into `<pluginManagement>`.

Put the execution into `<plugins>`.

Use `<inherited>false</inherited>`.

Comment: Looked like the `inherited` tag is what I need.  But with the configuration on pluginManagement, the child projects would still have to declare that plugin, correct?  Why do you recommend that instead of just leaving it in the plugins section, with the default `inherited` value?

Comment: You can try that as well. Usually, you need not declare the jar plugin anyway because it is part of the standard jar lifecycle.